# How do you reload and keep your reserve ammunition?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

When reloading in Advanced Warfare, there is something known as "Speed Reload" which let's you reload faster, at the cost of the entire magazine.

Being someone who has a somewhat bad habit of reloading after every kill, I do not want this to happen...

How do you reload normally and keep your magazine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speed reload is a new feature.

To perform a "classic" reload, tap "X" (on Xbox) or "Square" (on PS) **once**. This will reload your gun while keeping your ammo.

To perform a "quick" reload, tap the same button twice quickly. Your character will throw out the current mag, so you will lose the ammo that was remaining in it.

It's in fact very simple to test. Go into a private match, look at your total number of ammo (in mag and in reserve). Shoot 1 bullet, perform a quick reload, and look again at the total number of ammo. Do the same with a classic reload, and you'll see the number is not the same.

---

Edit:

As said by @Chantola, this might be broken at the time, and you should expect a fix in the next update.

Comment: It seems to work correctly in the firing range area, but in actual matches it is definitely buggy.

Comment: @Rapitor: I have to admit I didn't even notice it's not working correctly in actual matches, I thought it was saving me some ammo but I guess not so much :)

Comment: @Rapitor: SledgeHammer Games released the first patch for AW (available on PC and PS, soon on Xbox), correcting the speed reload bug.

Answer (score 2):

> **This has been addressed before as a glitch that happens to some people, randomly.**

There is no fix yet, not even a temporary one. Your unfortunately going to have to live with it (at-least for now), until they patch this bug up.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/792618-call-of-duty-advanced-warfare/70482065?page=2)

Comment: that makes sense, seeing as sometimes I keep me ammo and sometimes not. Do you know how to do the different reloads for when the bug is fixed?